# Sharing TypeScript code between Node.js and Vue.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vue.js

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this.  My environment is:

- Node.js 16.1.x
- Vue.js 3.x
- TypeScript 4.2.4

My directory structure is like this:

- Root (Node.js server)

  - shared

    - MySharedFile.ts
  - ui (Vue.js code)

`MySharedFile.ts` is exporting a very simple module:

```
export const MyShared = {
  TEST: 1
};
```

In Vue.js, I'm trying to import this module `import {MyShared} from '../../shared/MySharedFile'`, but when the app builds, I get the error `Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'`.  I've searched and found [a thread](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-eslint/issues/462) that suggests changing the eslintrc settings, which didn't work.  This error really doesn't make sense to me, so what does it mean, and how can I fix it?

**ui/tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    // https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/1138
    "importsNotUsedAsValues": "preserve",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**ui/.eslintrc.js**

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  extends: [
    '@vue/typescript',
    'plugin:vue/vue3-recommended',
    'plugin:vue/vue3-essential',
    'eslint:recommended',
    '@vue/typescript/recommended'
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 11,
    sourceType: 'module',
    allowImportExportEverywhere: true
  }
}
```

For anyone wanting the [source code](https://filebin.net/nmod16fdevjuxk5l)... I'm now at a new error **Parsing error: ‘import’ and ‘export’ may appear only with ‘sourceType: module’**

Comment: I'm starting to think the problem stems from the TS files aren't compiled into JS, and the Vue compiler doesn't include it by default because it's a sibling dir.  My Node.js tsconfig does include the shared dir in the compilation of the server, so that's why I don't have issues importing in Node.

Comment: Okay, it appears to be an eslint issue... I uninstalled eslint `npm remove @vue/cli-plugin-eslint`, and the error is no longer present, so I at least know where the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

I learned a few things with this.  The first is that I'm using what's referred to as a `monorepo`.  The second was that I should be using some sort of workspace, and I ended up using [npm workspaces](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces), but there're other options, like [yarn workspaces](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/workspaces/).  I had to refactor my app to follow a different structure, so I now have something like this:

- Root (main workspace)

  - api (Node.js)

    - package.json (`"dependencies": {"shared": "^1.0.0"}`)
    - tsconfig.json
    - <strike>package-lock.json</strike> (removed this)
  - shared (TypeScript code)

    - package.json (`"version": "1.0.0"`)
    - tsconfig.json
  - ui (Vue.js)

    - package.json (`"dependencies": {"shared": "^1.0.0"}`)
    - tsconfig.json
    - <strike>package-lock.json</strike> (removed this)
  - package.json (`"workspaces": ["api", "shared", "ui"]`)
  - package-lock.json (this gets generated and now contains all deps for workspaces)

After moving to this structure, I didn't have to modify the `tsconfig.json` or `vue.config.js` files to add the `shared` dir, as I could reference it like any other package when importing.  I also like this approach because it keeps all of my `node_modules` in one dir at the main workspace level.